# series declared dynamically Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Good evening, 
I made a chart visible in [`http://jsfiddle.net/6u7fW/1/`](http://jsfiddle.net/6u7fW/1/). 
As it turns out, I have defined the variable "data" as an array, since we do not know their numbers (in the graph are three, but could be more).

you can declare the variable "series" in a dynamic way, so that from then code it is possible to enter all the data ("data") and that it is not static?

```
series: [{
    name: name,
    data: data[2]
},
{
    name: name,
    data: data[1]
},
{
    name: "",
    data: data[0]
}]
```

Thank you in advance 
Dave

Comment: what is your problem for which you are looking out for a solution

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain:

you can do something like:

```
series: function() {
for (i=0; i <data.length; i++) {
return { name: "", data: data[i]}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
var len = data.length,
    series = [],
    i;

for(i=0;i<len;i++){
   series.push({ name: "", data: data[i]});
}

//highcharts part

series: series
```